# Transform every row in a column to date, using first unix_timestamp

Tags: hive, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have rows with the following format and I would like to transform then into valid Hive timestamps. Format in my data:

```
28/04/2017 00:00:00|20550|22/05/2017 00:00:00|
```

I'm only interested in the first and third column, separated with |, in MY case the format is, then:

```
dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss
```

I've discovered this can't be used as timestamp in Hive.

I find myself unable to transform all that first and third column to the proper format using queries similar to:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('28/04/2017','dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from `20170428_f_pers_pers`
```

I'm trying different instances of that query but since I can't access the documentation (internet is capped here at work), I can't see how to properly use this two functions, `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`

I've made the following assumptions:

1. I can reorder the days and years. If this isn't true, I have no idea how to transform my original data into proper Hive format
2. When I do this select, it affects the whole column. Further, after doing this with success I should be able to change the format of the whole column from string to timestamp (maybe I have to create a new column for that, not sure)

I do not care about doing both columns at once, but right now when I do the query showed first I get as many nulls as data has my table, and I'm unsure my assumptions are even partially right since every example I come accross is simpler (they do not change days and years arround, for instance).

I would like to know how to apply the query to a specific column, since I haven't understood how to do that from the examples studied so far. I do not see them using any type of column ID for that, which is weird to me, using data from the column to change the column itself.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I am now trying something like

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(f_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) from `myTable`
```

But I get from HUE the following error:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be completely covered by the input string.
In other words -
The format can be equal in length to the the input string or shorter, but not longer.

```
28/04/2017 00:00:00
|||||||||||||||||||
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

---

```
select  from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('28/04/2017 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

> 2017-04-28 00:00:00

---

```
28/04/2017 00:00:00
||||||||||
dd/MM/yyyy
```

---

```
select  from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('28/04/2017 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

> 2017-04-28 00:00:00

---

The result can be converted from string to timestamp using `cast`

```
select cast (from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('28/04/2017 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp)
```

Comment: I see... Is it possible to apply that query to all data in a column? The idea is at the end to have data as timestamp, is that possible? Maybe that's why the query keeps failing me

Comment: That's trully very helpful to me, since I was looking for the way to cast it too. But, if instead of only 1 row, I have 2000, is it possible to apply that operation to the whole column? For example, if the '28/04/2017 00:00:00' was in column "date", how could you apply this operation that you've shown me it works, to every single row in that column? Is it possible?

Comment: Off-course it is possible. Scalar functions works on expressions. Why would there be any difference between hard-coded expression and a column name? Why would there be any difference between querying a table with 2000 rows and querying a "table" with a single row?

Comment: Because when I switch your working example with a column name and a table, the query fails :S I'm using this, slightly adapted from your example: select cast (from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(f_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp) from `table`

Comment: If there is a failure, it is most likely not related to your post/my answer. If my example works for you "as is" then open a new question for you error and include the full stack trace

Comment: Yes, the example you provided it works and is very helpful to me, but would you mind confirming me that syntax for a particular column is right? Like, I can then dig somewhere else, but it's so messed up for me to have a working query that fails for something else... Just want to discard the option... Sorry to bother

Comment: The syntax you have provided (using `f_date`) is fine, as long as your table name is not really `table` or other reserved word.

Comment: Didn't know it was a reserved work but yeah, indeed is not that name. Thanks a lot for the help, I will try narrow where the problem is if the syntax is fine